# Flex problem : order elements + 2 columns

Tags: css, flexbox

Thanks to flexbox, based on this code, I would like col-1, col-3 and col-5 to be placed below each other in a column on the right and col-2 and col-4 to be placed below each other. below the others in a left column.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">TEXTE 1</div>
    <div class="col-2">VIDEO 1</div>
    <div class="col-3">TEXTE 2</div>
    <div class="col-4">VIDEO 2</div>
    <div class="col-5">TEXTE 3</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible ?

The desired result: texts on the left and videos on the right.
I tried this CSS but the videos stay below the texts. Columns do not work.

```
section.cta-video .row{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    section.cta-video .row .col-1, section.cta-video .row .col-3, section.cta-video .row .col-5 {
        order: 1;
        flex-basis: 50%;
    }

    section.cta-video .row .col-2, section.cta-video .row .col-4 {
        order: 2;
        flex-basis: 50%;
    }
```

Comment: consider using bootstrap. This makes working in columns way easier: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/columns/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it necessary that it's a `flex` layout?

You can achieve this easily using `grid`.

`grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr` turns it into a 2-column layout.

You can then use the `nth-child` pseudo selectors to select all even-numbered children to start in the first grid column, and all the odd-numbered children to start in the second grid column:

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense; /* returns it to a normal layout */
}

.row div:nth-child(even) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.row div:nth-child(odd) {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1">TEXTE 1</div>
  <div class="col-2">VIDEO 1</div>
  <div class="col-3">TEXTE 2</div>
  <div class="col-4">VIDEO 2</div>
  <div class="col-5">TEXTE 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: THANKS. Small problem: the texts overlap in the left column. How to put them under each other?

Comment: By default, they shouldn't overlap with the code I provided. That's most likely caused by some other CSS code. I can't help you with that unless you provide me with some more code @RaphaelM

Answer (score 1):

You can use grid, in particular `grid-template-areas` to solve this:

More info on grid-template-areas on [CSS tricks here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/grid-template-areas/)

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a b" "c d" "e f";
}

.col-1 { grid-area:b; }
.col-3 { grid-area:d; }
.col-5 { grid-area:f; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1">TEXTE 1</div>
  <div class="col-2">VIDEO 1</div>
  <div class="col-3">TEXTE 2</div>
  <div class="col-4">VIDEO 2</div>
  <div class="col-5">TEXTE 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: THANKS. Small problem: the texts overlap in the left column. How to put them under each other?